# replace string with underscore and dots using sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a bunch of files with filenames composed of underscore and dots, here is one example:

```
META_ALL_whrAdjBMI_GLOBAL_August2016.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz.r0-ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA.out.params
```

I want to remove the part that contains `.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz.` so the expected filename output would be `META_ALL_whrAdjBMI_GLOBAL_August2016.r0-ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA.out.params`

I am using these sed commands but neither one works:

```
stringZ=META_ALL_whrAdjBMI_GLOBAL_August2016.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz.r0-ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA.out.params
echo $stringZ | sed -e 's/\([[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.\)//g'
echo $stringZ | sed -e 's/\[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.[[:lower:]]\.//g'
```

Any solution is sed or awk would help a lot

Comment: So do you want to remove from all those filenames the exact same substring (i.e. `bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz.`)?

Comment: yes @redneb, the same substring is repeated across filenames. I was trying to use a regexp to match the substring

Comment: If you have a fixed substring, what do you need the regex for? Just use the substring itself as the pattern.

Comment: I'd like to have something more general because I have another files with similar pattern, but this time the substring change in each file

Comment: If _the substring change in each file_, then make it clear in your question, and we'll give you the most appropriate answer. As of now, the answer you accepted is far from being a good option for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex doesn't really feel too much more general than the fixed pattern would be, but if you want to make it work, you need to allow for more than one lower case character between each dot.  Right now you're looking for exactly one, but you can fix it with `\+` after each `[[:lower:]]` like

```
printf '%s' "$stringZ" | sed -e 's/\([[:lower:]]\+\.[[:lower:]]\+\.[[:lower:]]\+\.[[:lower:]]\+\.[[:lower:]]\+\.[[:lower:]]\+\.[[:lower:]]\+\.\)//g'
```

which with

```
stringZ="META_ALL_whrAdjBMI_GLOBAL_August2016.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz.r0-ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA.out.params"
```

give me the output

```
META_ALL_whrAdjBMI_GLOBAL_August2016.r0-ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA.out.params
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use external utilities and regexes for such a simple task! Use [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead.

```
stringZ=META_ALL_whrAdjBMI_GLOBAL_August2016.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz.r0-ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA.out.params
echo "${stringZ/.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz}"
```

To perform the renaming of all the files containing `.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz`, use this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
substring=.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz
for file in *"$substring"*; do
    echo mv -- "$file" "${file/"$substring"}"
done
```

**Note.** I left `echo` in front of `mv` so that nothing is going to be renamed; the commands will only be displayed on your terminal. Remove `echo` if you're satisfied with what you see.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $(ls -1 META*);
do
f2=$(echo $line | sed 's/.bed.nodup.sortedbed.roadmap.sort.fgwas.gz//')
mv $line $f2
done
```

Comment: This contains more mistakes then there are lines of code. google parsing ls output, quoting shell variables, regexp metacharacters and read the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson or similar.

Comment: No, they are basic so if you don't know these then there's a lot more you also don't know and so you really need to read to read some kind of introductory shell programming text to learn the fundamentals rather than just focusing on the 5 or so errors in this script. Also you can find info about some of them by just googling like I said. Finally - compare your answer to [@gniourf_gniourf's correct one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39546900/1745001) and notice the differences.